# ラズベリー3とPCとのブルトゥース通信トラブル

Tags: raspberry-pi, bluetooth

ラズベリー3とPCとのブルトゥース通信プログラムを作成しています。TeraTermでの通信は問題なくできるのですが、VBを使ったプログラムでは、安定した状態で接続ができません。

ラズベリ側のブルートゥース関連のバージョンは、

- bluej 3.1.7b
- bluez 5.23-2 rpi2
- bluez firmware 1.2-3 rpi2
- pi-bluetooth 0.1.3 1
- OSは4.9.35-v7 wheezy

PC側は

- Windows10
- TeraTerm バージョン 4.95
- ボーレート115200 データ8ビット パリティなし ストップビット１ フロー制御（任意）

通信プログラムは

- PC側

  - Visual Studio2012のVisualBasic SirialPortモジュール 使用
  - ボーレート115200 データ8ビット パリティなし ストップビット１フロー制御〔任意）、DTR,RTS 有効
- ラズベリ側

  - `rfcomm listen /dev/rfcomm0 ポート番号` で接続待ち

このような条件で、TeraTermでは、安定してつながるのですが、VBプログラムではPC側が「プログラム起動ON、接続ON」直後に切断となりました。再度これらの動作を数回繰り返すと初めて接続が維持され、通信が可能となります。（接続がON・切断のどちらかであるかは、ラズベリデスクトップ上部のブルトゥースアイコンもしくはコマンド `rfcomm` で確認）

VBで接続が安定しない原因、解消法をご存知でしたら、教えて下さい。
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: コピペミスと思われる箇所や改行位置などがおかしい部分がありますので文章を校正／修正できますでしょうか？

Comment: Myakuさま　ご指摘有難うございました。